# My button does not move to the upper right corner from the left side via javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have button in html that is on the middle left of the screen, that button is styled such as:

```
  .openbtn {
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: fixed;
      Top: 50%;
      left: 0px;
      background-color: #181A1B;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border: none;
      z-index: 1;
      transition: 0.5s;
  }
```

now when i click this button i want it to transfer to the upper right and when i click again it should go back to its original position. In Javascript the button is handled as so:

```
    var lastState = false;

    function sideButtonClicked() {

      if(!lastState){
          //open
          lastState=true
          document.getElementById("Button").style.left = "";
          document.getElementById("Button").style.right = "0";
          document.getElementById("Button").style.top = "0";
      }
      else{
          //close
          lastState=false
          document.getElementById("Button").style.left = "0px";
          document.getElementById("Button").style.right = "";
          document.getElementById("Button").style.top = "50%";
      }
```

I find this tricking because if i want to play that button on the upper right corner is when i declare it on css i dont place the left property but since its initial position is in the left i have to declare it. I tried setting it to "" but it does not work. What i know works is the button moves up/down upon clicking the button,
        }

Comment: The best way to accomplish that is just to add/remove a class that has the styling that you're looking for.

Comment: so have two buttons? and just show 1 at a time? A good solution if there is no other way, i might do that

Comment: No. You have the default styling of the button, let's call `btn`. Then you add CSS styling for `.btn .activeStyling` and you add the styling there. Then - you just toggle the class on/off with the javascript btn event.

Comment: @JoelHager can you provide a sample code good sir? If it works i will gladly accept it as answer. Im new to this, if you can explain how it works that would also be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple example of how to toggle classes in vanilla JS. Then, you just do your styling via CSS.

```js
// Cache the DOM element for continued use
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

// Attach event listener to button for 'click' event
btn.addEventListener("click", () =>

{
  // Where we see if it has the class or not
  
  // Is it inactive?
  if (!btn.classList.contains("active"))
    {
      console.log("Added");
      btn.classList.add("active");
    } else // If it *is* currently active
    {
      console.log("Removed");
      btn.classList.remove("active");
    }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.btn.active {
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Essentially, you're using a CSS class as a target for the different styling and just using JS to turn the class on/off. That way, you can just edit the 'toggle' class in CSS to whatever you want and the code will always work. This is usually what we use for sticky navbars, etc. You just add/remove another class, and that overrides the default styling.

Comment: You can also use @keyframes to animate position in CSS. ;)

Comment: it a shame that i have to sacrifice the transition of it going diagonally. i guess ill compromise on fade in and out

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. You can use @keyframes to animate a translate(X) or Y to move the container. Any image or example of what you're looking for?

Comment: I spoke too soon, Keyframes i think will do the trick and i can still have my transition animation, thank you for introducing the feature to me good sir

Comment: I can amend my answer to include an animation if you explain what you'd like it to do. :)